# i want a sql query to do select unique result from chatting where senderid=3 or receiverid=3 order by I'd desc limit 0,10

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called chatting. 
I want these condition.

```
select all distinct result 
from chatting 
where senderid=3 or receiverid=3 
order by Id desc 
limit 0,10
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDqAI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXgRV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQtig.png)

my output is showing the same mane more than 1 times. I want per name 1 times and I want to use this SQL query in php page with all these conditions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you are commanding/looking for one to do your homework. Please show your research and where you are facing technical difficulties.

Comment: No i am not doing any homwwork. i am designing site there i need it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this example

```
<?php
        $resulte = mysqli_query($connection, "select DISTINCT senderid from chatting where senderid!=3 OR receiverid =3 UNION select DISTINCT receiverid from chatting where senderid=3 OR receiverid !=3 ORDER BY senderid desc limit 0,10"); 
$rowe = mysqli_fetch_array($resulte); 

if (!$resulte) {die("Error: Data not found..");}
else{

...loop

}
```

Comment: i need all condition like --result must be unique..  order by id DESC ,limit 0,10 ............... your code showing 3 3 3 6 7 5 6 4.. ...  i need only 3 6 7 54

Comment: i dont know what you mean but do you want just one row in return

Comment: bro i dont need distint id... i need distinct senderid and receiverid.

Comment: but if you select a distinct id and you have where condition with senderid=3 it will be always 3

Comment: i have updated question , added some images.. please check and help

Comment: as i anderstand you need to distinct the msg right ?

Comment: no.. i have 2 tables -- chatting - from where i need a distinct senderid or recerverid and another table called user where i have id and username.. i am getting id from chatting table and using it to fatch username from user table.. home you understand

Comment: bro now i am getting distinct senderid but not receiverid..      senderid
6
5
4
3
receiverid 3 3 3 4

Comment: check again you need to separate then u can use union all with 2 separate query

Comment: thankyou bro finally i have done it.. select DISTINCT senderid from chatting where senderid!=3 OR receiverid =3 UNION select DISTINCT receiverid from chatting where senderid=3 OR receiverid !=3 ORDER BY senderid desc limit 0,10

Comment: you welcome bro i update my answer with your query to be usefull for pepeole , u can vote up and mark as a answer